# Mr. Service, Expose this methods or I won't call you, Sincerely Remote Program

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, design-patterns, soa

I have to develop a "big soft" and smaller *"satellite-Adapter"* services (remote) which the big soft can call.

Every *"satellite-Adapter"* implements the same methods

What I need is to provide **from the big soft a Contract Interface** (method_names with object sent as parameter, object received as return) **which every *"satellite-Adapter"* service is *tacitly forced* to implement** in order to be called by the big soft. This way I may be developing the big soft only once and can add as plug-ins the new Adapters.

Also calling new Adapters developed afterwards should only be a URI change.

Questions:

1. Is there a Pattern for SOA that solves this issue? Does this have a name which I could be looking for on the web?
2. If it's not a pattern, it certainly sounds as something that has been required before. Where can I find examples of this solved in C#?
3. Could you orient me with a way to solve this in.net?

Answer (score 2):

You define the contract using an `interface`:

```
public interface IMyContract {

    // Methods, properties, etc. that the contract needs defined
}
```

Your different "satellite-Adapter" services implement the contract this way:

```
public class MySuperDuperService : IMyContract {

    // Properties & methods particular to what this service does.
    // You must provide an implementation for every property & method defined by IMyContract in here, too.
}
```

Your "big soft" program can have a property or multiple properties that hold a reference to an instance of a class that implements the `interface`, or it can have methods that are passed a reference to an object that implements the service:

```
public class BigSoft {

    public IMyContract SatelliteAdapter { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething( IMyContract adapter ) {
        // code here
    }
```

}

And so on.  In this way, `BigSoft` doesn't know anything about what each service does, but it can use any of them because it expects each one to have the same methods & properties, and they do.  The compiler won't build an executable until all properties & methods defined in the IMyContract `interface` are defined in each satellite-adapter class.

Another thing you should know:  a class can descend from only one class, but it can implement all of the interfaces you want it to.  That is,

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase, IMyContract1, IMyContract2 { . . . }
```

is totally legal only if:

- Everything in the comma separated list is an interface, or
- ServiceBase is a class and IMyContract1, IMyContract2 are interfaces.

A common convention is to use a capital "I" as the first letter of all `interfaces`, which is what I did in the example, so you can look at the code & know that `ServiceBase` must be a class and the other two must be `interfaces`.  Also, if you want to descend your new class from an existing class, the super class name must be first in the list.

Comment: To clarify, just by adding the reference on the adapter and implementing the interface (which the adapter itself only knows it from the reference) and creating that interface on the remote BigSoft is enough?
Also: Is this aligned with any pattern?

Comment: I believe this is called the service pattern, but I haven't made a study of the standard patterns out there.  I started programming before "patterns" were a thing in computer science.  When you say "adding the reference on the adapter", are you referring to the `public class MyService : IMyContract { . . . }` line?  If so, yes.  That says, "this class implements the `IMyContract` interface", and that's all that `BigSoft` needs.

Comment: You can't make an interface serializable, only a concrete class.  To do that, your class has to implement the `ISerializable` interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx)